# ¿Comó selecionar elementos aleatoreos de un array y sumarlos?

Tags: java

El problema que tengo es el de seleccionar números de un arreglo de n elementos (números enteros)de forma aleatoria, por ejemplo tengo un arreglo de 10 elementos
{3, 5, 6, 1, 9, 23, 75, 67, 2, 3} y de esos seleccionar {3, 23, 2, 1, 6} y de estos 5 números seleccionados realizar su suma que en este caso seria 35

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Si lo que queres es seleccionar aleatoriamente **n** elemento de tu arrar, tenes que generar un número aleatorio importando la clase Math a tu codigo

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Despues genera un número aleatorio entre 0 y **n** (Cantidad de elementos en tu array) y guardalo en una variable

```
numAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * n);
```

En tercer lugar, a ese fragmento anterior lo tenes que introducir en un ciclo, como el for, indicando cuantas veces queres que genere un número aleatorio. En este caso 5.

```
int suma = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    numAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * n);
    suma = suma + lista[numAleatorio];
}
```

Por ultimo, te queda mostrar por pantalla el resultado de la suma de dichos números

```
System.out.println("La suma de los números es: " + suma);
```

Comment: No cumple lo que pide el OP, hay que seleccionar 5 distintos. Este código puede seleccionar 5 iguales.

Comment: Como usuario con algo de experiencia deberías saber que no hay que responder preguntas que no demuestren que haya detrás algo de trbajo e investigación. El OP ha puesto su pregunta como una tarea del colegio y así no hay que resolver las dudas hasta que edite su pregunta y la mejore.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda